# Trying to draw multiple flowers using a loop

Tags: java, swing, drawing

**This is a project that I have to do for my programming class...and I'm struggling pretty bad at it so I'm hoping someone here can help me or at least point me in the right direction :)**

The requirements for the project are (translating from Dutch):

1. 1 fixed drawn object - a flowerpot.
2. 1 object that is repeated a number of times according to a 'total' given in a textbox. Plant these flowers in the flowerpot.(a flower has atleast a stem and a flower)
3. with minimum 1 textbox where a total (type int) is typed in. This total stands for the total number of flowers that have to be drawn. Do this with a loop.
4. Make a textbox for the colour of the flowers and add red, yellow, orange and a few other colours. With each modification of the colour, the flowers change colour.A listbox would be even better.
5. Make a button where the flower bud doubles in size and another button returning the flower to its initial size.
6. Minimum of one or more text boxes where the size of an object can be given as well as a total.The distance between the objects depend on the given size. These objects can be anything ex. watering can, glass of water, mini-farmer...Let your fantasy work.
7. Add a comment to each drawn object. With this you say what exactly is being drawn.
8. Also make use of an image.

**So far I've managed to draw one flower and I've gotten my loop to work more or less...but the positions get messed up. I'm using Netbeans. Here is the code from my panel:**

```
    package Versie4;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;

public class PanelFlowers extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    private int amount;

    public PanelFlowers() {
        initComponents();
        repaint();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);

        int teller;

        g.setColor(Color.RED);  //flowerpot
        g.fillRect(300, 350, 500, 100);

        for (teller=1; teller <= amount ;teller++) { 

            //Flower 1
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);  //stem
        g.fillRect(320 * teller, 250, 10, 100);


        g.setColor(Color.PINK); //petals
        g.fillOval(304 * teller, 190, 40, 40);
        g.fillOval(330 * teller, 210, 40, 40);
        g.fillOval(320 * teller, 240, 40, 40);
        g.fillOval(290 * teller, 240, 40, 40);
        g.fillOval(280 * teller, 210, 40, 40);

        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);  //pistil
        g.fillOval(312 * teller, 225, 25, 25);




        }


    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        lblamount = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        txtamount = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        lblcolor = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        txtcolor = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        btngrow = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnreset = new javax.swing.JButton();

        lblamount.setText("Amount: ");

        txtamount.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                txtamountActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        lblcolor.setText("Color: ");

        btngrow.setText("Grow!");

        btnreset.setText("Reset Size");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(lblamount)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(txtamount, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 57, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(41, 41, 41)
                .addComponent(lblcolor)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(txtcolor, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 59, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(60, 60, 60)
                .addComponent(btngrow)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(btnreset)
                .addContainerGap(230, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(lblamount)
                    .addComponent(txtamount, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(lblcolor)
                    .addComponent(txtcolor, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(btngrow)
                    .addComponent(btnreset))
                .addContainerGap(412, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void txtamountActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
amount = Integer.parseInt(txtamount.getText());
repaint();
    }                                         

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton btngrow;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnreset;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblamount;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblcolor;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtamount;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtcolor;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

**And here is the frame:**

```
package Versie4;


public class FrameFlowers extends javax.swing.JFrame {


    public FrameFlowers() {
        initComponents();
        setSize(900, 600);
        setContentPane(new PanelFlowers());
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FrameFlowers.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FrameFlowers.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FrameFlowers.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FrameFlowers.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new FrameFlowers().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: I am not pretty clear about the positioning problem you are having. And `suck` `screw` are probably not a good fit for this site. Try posting a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org): a compilable, runnable, short in size and able to produce your problem. As you have pinpointed the issue in your bold text, the project's option list is unnecessary

Comment: My problem is the first flower works fine but as soon as I try to add more the petals ect aren't in the correct positions.

I added the list to make sure people understand what I'm trying to achieve. And if someone perhaps has a better idea on how to approach the project then that would be helpful as well.

Comment: I have added a solution below. Please check, and off-course their are better ideas to approach the project. But it will make the area of the answer too broad. However you can start learning layout manager as i have mentioned in the answer

Comment: However, i will give you a +1 upvote for attaching the SSCCE. I am removing the odd words from the question, hope you won't mind. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When you are trying to shift the position of the flower horizontally, you were trying to multiply. Your thinking was all most right. But Multiplying same integer to different `petals` will not create same amount of shifting. Rather lets use a variable *delta* `x` which will shift the flower including the petals with the delta `x` we define. We will however multiply `teller` to this `delta` and then add it to the oval's x co-ordinate to ensure that all petals `x` co-ordinates are shifting relatively in uniform.

   ```
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
       super.paintComponent(g);

       int teller;

       g.setColor(Color.RED);  //flowerpot
       g.fillRect(300, 350, 500, 100);


       int x = 1;
       for (teller=1; teller <= amount ;teller++) { 

           //Flower 1
       g.setColor(Color.GREEN);  //stem
       g.fillRect(320 + x, 250, 10, 100);


       g.setColor(Color.PINK); //petals
       g.fillOval(304 + x, 190, 40, 40);
       g.fillOval(330 + x, 210, 40, 40);
       g.fillOval(320 + x, 240, 40, 40);
       g.fillOval(290 + x, 240, 40, 40);
       g.fillOval(280 + x, 210, 40, 40);

       g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);  //pistil
       g.fillOval(312 + x, 225, 25, 25);

        x = teller * 80;  
             //<---- here we are multiplying with the teller a fixed amount 


       }


   }
   ```

   Here, adjust the above code with yours one, and feast your eyes.
2. Try to [learn layout managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html), instead of depending on the NetBean's free design support. There are really nice layout developed to help us working with. And they will make you happy in the end.